# Shell script to batch download files using curl + cookie and merge those files

Tags: shell, curl

I have a list of urls to files that I want to download and join. Those can only be accessed when authenticated.
So first I call:

```
curl -c cookie.txt http://url.to.authenticate
```

Then I can download a file `file1` using the cookie:

```
curl -b cookie.txt -O http://url.to.file1
```

At the end I would just use `cat`:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 ... > file_merged
```

I have 320 of those urls stored in a text file and want to create a script with these urls included in the script, so all I need is to copy the script to a remote computer and execute it.
I am not that good at shell scripting and would love it if someone could help me out a bit.
Maybe something a little more fail-proof than

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -c cookie.txt http://url.to.authenticate
curl -b cookie.txt -O http://url.to.file1
curl -b cookie.txt -O http://url.to.file2
curl -b cookie.txt -O http://url.to.file3
...
cat file1 file2 file3 ... file320 > file_merged
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, something like (if your list of files is stored in files.txt):

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -c cookie.txt http://url.to.authenticate
while read f; do
    curl -b cookie.txt -O http://url.to."$f"
    cat "$f" >> file_merged
    rm -f "$f"
done < files.txt
```